# R Shiny histogram as elements of renderTable

Tags: r, plot, grid, shiny

I use a data frame to receive inputs from the user interface. To simplify, let's say that it's 2 rows and 2 columns. Based on the inputs, I would like to plot distributions. The challenge is that I need the distributions to be presented in the same way, i.e. in the format of a "matrix".

I provide a reproducible example here below. What I understand from the error messages is the following: once I enter data in the input matrix, the receiving matrix is not able to replace its elements (which are numeric in general) by plots. Probably I should tell the receiving data frame that its elements won't be "standard", but I don't know how. Also, maybe I should use javascript or html to define the histograms ?

Here is a simplified version of my ui.R and server.R:

ui.R:

```
shinyUI(navbarPage(
  "My Application",
  tabPanel("Component 1",
       fluidPage(

         tableOutput('decision_Matrix'),

         tableOutput('decision_Matrix_plots')
       )),
tabPanel("Component 2")
))
```

server.R:

```
shinyServer(

function(input, output) {

output$decision_Matrix <- renderTable({

  matrix_input <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=2,ncol=2)

  for (j in 1:2) {
    for (i in 1:2) {

      matrix_input[i,j] <- paste0("<input id='C", j, "_A", i, "' type='number' class='form-control shiny-bound-input'  value='", input[[paste0("C", j, "_A", i)]], "'>")

    }
  }

  rownames(matrix_input) <- c("alt1","alt2") 
  colnames(matrix_input) <- c("crit1","crit2") 

  matrix_input

},include.rownames=TRUE, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)  

output$decision_Matrix_plots <- renderTable({ 

  matrix_plots <- data.frame()

  for (j in 1:2) {
    for (i in 1:2) {

      n <- input[[paste0("C", j,"_A",i)]]

      matrix_plots[i,j] <- hist(rnorm(n),breaks=10)  # here is where it is not correct I think

    }}

  matrix_plots
})

})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you !

H

[image]

Comment: You can set breakpoints to see what the value and class of `n` is.

Comment: it's not clear exactly what value you want to have in matrix_plots[i,j].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't have had to research as much if you were using `ggplot` (I would have just used `grid.arrange`) but this turned out to be fairly straightforward too.

Note that I changed your 2nd `renderTable` to a `renderPlot`. Also I arranged your base graphics with `layout` and then used the `gridBase` function called `recordPlot` to convert your base graphics to a grid-based plot and returned that.

Per-request, I also scaled the plot to be 800 pixels wide and added some CSS styling on the `renderTable` to match.

```
library(shiny)
library(grid)
library(gridBase)

u <- shinyUI(navbarPage(
  "My Application",
  tabPanel("Component 1",
       fluidPage(
         tableOutput('decision_Matrix'),
         tags$head(tags$style("#decision_Matrix table {background-color: lightgray; width: 800px; }",media = "screen",type = "text/css")),
         plotOutput('decision_Matrix_plots')
       )),
tabPanel("Component 2")
))

s <- shinyServer(

function(input,output) {

  output$decision_Matrix <- renderTable({
    matrix_input <- matrix(data = NA,nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
    for (j in 1:2) {
      for (i in 1:2) {
        matrix_input[i,j] <- paste0("<input id='C",j,"_A",i,"' type='number' class='form-control shiny-bound-input'  value='",input[[paste0("C",j,"_A",i)]],"'>")
      }
    }
    rownames(matrix_input) <- c("alt1","alt2")
    colnames(matrix_input) <- c("crit1","crit2")
    matrix_input
  },include.rownames = TRUE,sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)

  output$decision_Matrix_plots <- renderPlot(width=800,height=500,{
    layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow = 2,ncol = 2))
    for (j in 1:2) {
      for (i in 1:2) {
        set.seed(123)
        n <- input[[paste0("C",j,"_A",i)]]
        if (is.null(n) || is.na(n) || n < 1) n <- 1
        hist(rnorm(n),breaks = 10,main=sprintf("histogram of rnorm( %d )",n))
      }
    }
    recordPlot()
  })
})
shinyApp(ui = u,server = s)
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Mike Wise. This works well indeed. I was thinking of using renderTable instead of renderPlot, so that the plots would have the same dimension horizontally as the input matrix. At the moment, the plots are much wider than the inputs dataframe at the top of the page. I presume I can use fluidPage and column to make sure that they align ?

Comment: I adjusted the width of the two elements to be the same, the `renderTable` with CSS commands, and the `renderPlot` by specifying the size of the image. There are other ways to do it too, but these are the most straightforward I think without getting all bootstrapy.

Comment: This is an elegant solution !

Comment: A follow-up question: is it possible to have the plots appear inside the inputs table at the top (and not as a separate panel below). I mean, for example, the first histogram would appear in position [1,1] in the table, just under the input ("5" in the example above), and similarly for the other plots. The plots don't have to big as big as in the example above, but should fit in the table just under the numerical inputs. I've spent the whole day on this yesterday without success. Thank you.